# How to update multiple models using a single form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So i have been trying to update three models i.e.,

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from postlog.models import FlightNum


class pnr(models.Model):
    pnr=models.CharField(max_length=9,primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pnr

class name(models.Model):
    pnr=models.OneToOneField(pnr,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='p1')
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class passenger(models.Model):
    pnr=models.OneToOneField(pnr,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,related_name='p2')
    name=models.ForeignKey(name,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dob=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    passport_no= models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    fl_no=models.ForeignKey (FlightNum,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,unique=False)
```

So what I'm trying to do is create a form where i can take input from the user for pnr,name,dob,passport_no and update all three models at the same time

i have created 3 model forms which look like this:

**forms.py:**

```
from Django.forms import ModelForm
from postlog.models import FlightNum
from passenger.models import pnr,name,passenger

class pnrForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = pnr
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'pnr' : ('PNR')
        }

class nameForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = name
        fields = ('name',)
        labels = {
            'name' : ('Name')
        }

class passenForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = passenger
        fields = ('dob', 'passport_no', 'fl_no')
        labels = {
            'dob' : ('Date Of Birth'),
            'passport_no' : ('Passport Number'),
            'fl_no' : ('Flight Number'),
        }
```

my **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from passenger.forms import passenForm, pnrForm, nameForm
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

def passengerAdd(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        formA = pnrForm(request.POST, prefix= 'pnr')
        formB = nameForm(request.POST, prefix= 'name')
        formC = passenForm(request.POST, prefix= 'pass')
        if formA.is_valid() and formB.is_valid() and formC.is_valid():
            fa = formA.save()
            fb = formB.save(commit=False)
            fb.pnr = fa
            fb.save()
            fc = formC.save(commit=False)
            fc.pnr = fa
            fc.name = fb
            fc.save()
        return redirect(reverse('passenger_list'))
    else:
        formA = pnrForm(prefix = 'pnr')
        formB = nameForm(prefix = 'name')
        formC = passenForm(prefix = 'pass')
        args = {'formA' : formA, 'formB' : formB, 'formC' : formC}
        return render(request, 'passenger_add.html', args)
```

And i have included all the three forms in html template

the page looks like this [image: this]

Comment: Use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: but can i not do it this way I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible. I'm not sure how to use formset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns None because your forms seems like invalid and you have not returned anything when your forms are invalid, so, that's why it is returning None from the "passengerAdd" function

Note:- Python will return None when you don't return anything from the function
You can save multiple forms by passing instances to your form's save method.
Example:-

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import passenForm, pnrForm, nameForm
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


def passengerAdd(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        formA = pnrForm(request.POST, prefix='pnr')
        formB = nameForm(request.POST, prefix='name')
        formC = passenForm(request.POST, prefix='pass')

        if formA.is_valid() and formB.is_valid() and formC.is_valid():
            a = formA.save()
            b = formB.save(a)
            c = formC.save(a, b)
        return render(request, 'passenger/passenger_home.html')
    else:
        formA = pnrForm(prefix='pnr')
        formB = nameForm(prefix='name')
        formC = passenForm(prefix='pass')
        args = {'formA': formA, 'formB': formB, 'formC': formC}
        return render(request, 'passenger_add.html', args)
```

forms.py

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import pnr, name, passenger


class pnrForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = pnr
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'pnr': ('PNR')
        }


class nameForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = name
        fields = ('name',)
        labels = {
            'name': ('Name')
        }

    def save(self, b, commit=True):
        instance = super(nameForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if not self.instance.pk:
            # create
            if commit:
                instance.pnr = b
                instance.save()
        return instance


class passenForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = passenger
        fields = ('dob', 'passport_no')
        labels = {
            'dob': ('Date Of Birth'),
            'passport_no': ('Passport Number'),
        }

    def save(self, a, b, commit=True):
        instance = super(passenForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if not self.instance.pk:
            # create
            if commit:
                instance.pnr = a
                instance.name = b
                instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Thank You. But I have just made changes to the views file would really appreciate it if you could check it out. using my view that i have edited would add records to pnr model and name model but it doesn't add a record into the passenger model so if you could suggest changes to that i would really appreciate it

Comment: But I will surely try your method too